# How to read a very large integer (1000+ digits) that is saved in **multiple lines** in a text file using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a very large integer (say, of 1000+ digits) that I've saved into a text file named `'large_number.txt'`. But the problem is the integer has been divided into multiple lines in the file, i.e. like the following:

```
47451445736001306439091167216856844588711603153276
70386486105843025439939619828917593665686757934951
62176457141856560629502157223196586755079324193331
64906352462741904929101432445813822663347944758178
92575867718337217661963751590579239728245598838407
58203565325359399008402633568948830189458628227828
80181199384826282014278194139940567587151170094390
35398664372827112653829987240784473053190104293586
86515506006295864861532075273371959191420517255829
71693888707715466499115593487603532921714970056938
54370070576826684624621495650076471787294438377604
```

Now, I want to read this number from the file and use it as a regular integer in my program. I tried the following but I can't.

**My Try (Python):**

```
with open('large_number.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()
```

Is there any way to do this properly in Python 3.6 ? Or what best can be done in this situation?

Comment: `int(f.read().replace('\n', '').replace('\r', ''))` should work.

Comment: @Torxed: The `'\r'` replacement shouldn't be necessary, given that it's reading in text mode (so it's doing universal newline translation to `\n`, whether the input newlines are `\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n`).

Answer (score 3):

Just replace the newlines with nothing, then parse:

```
with open('large_number.txt') as f:
    data = int(f.read().replace('\n', ''))
```

If you might have arbitrary (ASCII) whitespace and you want to discard all of it, switch to:

```
import string

killwhitespace = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(string.whitespace))
with open('large_number.txt') as f:
    data = int(f.read().translate(killwhitespace))
```

Either way that's significantly more efficient than processing line-by-line in this case (because you need all the lines to parse, any line-by-line solution would be ugly), both in memory and runtime.

Comment: @Torxed: As I mentioned above, Python universal newline translation in text mode means you never actually receive the `\r` (the `\r\n` is converted to `\n` before it reaches you).

Comment: Yea noticed, I can't say I like this very much. I wouldn't want to automatically disrupt line endings just because I ran a document through Python. When did this change happen and how would I circumvent this without reading it in binary mode? Thought you needed to do `line_ending=None` to trigger this behavior..

Comment: @Torxed: Universal newlines mode has been the default for a while now. You can pass the `newline` argument to change the behavior; `newline=''` means it breaks lines at all recognized line terminators, but doesn't translate them (mandatory for use with `csv` module), while a non-empty string for `newline` (`'\n'`, `'\r'`, or `'\r\n'`) means that only that string is recognized as a newline, and it is returned untranslated (universal newlines completely disabled).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
 with open('large_number.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
    number = int(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.rstrip` to remove the trailing newline characters and use `str.join` to join the lines into one string:

```
with open('large_number.txt') as file:
    data = int(''.join(line.rstrip() for line in file))
```